# Redefining the output of a function

Tags: functions, syntax, variable-definitions

```
ftn1 = Sin[s]^2 + 3 t^2 + u^5
```

> 3 t^2 + u^5 + sin[s]^2

```
ftn2[s_, t_, u_] := ftn1

ftn2[2, 1, 2]
```

> 3 t^2 + u^5 + Sin[s]^2

Hi there,
In the above code, would somebody like to comment on how to redefine the output of ftn1 in the form ftn2[...] above. This is just a simple example, oftentimes there is a complicated output of ftn1 and one has to copy and paste for ftn2[....]. That's quite cumbersome, though works well. I am wondering how to directly define ftn2 in terms of the output of ftn1 above so that to avoid copy and paste and also ftn2 works fine. As it can be seen from above "ftn2[2, 1, 2]" fails to work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
ftn1 = Sin[s]^2 + 3 t^2 + u^5
ftn2[s_, t_, u_] = ftn1
a=ftn2[2, 1, 2]
N[a]
```

> 35 + Sin[2]^2

> 35.8268

If you prefer to used `:=` then

```
ftn1 = Sin[s]^2 + 3 t^2 + u^5
ftn2[s_, t_, u_] := Evaluate[ftn1]
```

Comment: Thanks, but the numerical value is not always required. The ftn2 has some free variables, which have to be plotted at a later stage. And this first output, 35+Sin[2]^2 is also not required.

Comment: Thanks, Summit. The second choice worked very well for me!

Answer (score 0):

Your function is defined as,

```
ftn1 = Sin[s]^2 + 3 t^2 + u^5
```

> 3 t^2 + u^5 + Sin[s]^2

If you use `ReplaceAll (/.)` on `ftn1`,

```
ftn1 /. {s -> 2, t -> 1, u -> 2}
```

> 35 + Sin[2]^2

You can use `N[]` to numerically evaluate it,

```
N[ftn1 /. {s -> 2, t -> 1, u -> 2}]
```

> 35.8268

With this knowledge, define `ftn2` as `ftn2[s1_, t1_, u1_]`, where `s1`, `t1` and `u1` are placeholders for `s`, `t` and `u` respectively. Now we "replace all" variables so that `ftn1` is evaluated inside the definition of `ftn2` (Techinically, by using `:=`, `fnt1` is not evaluated inside the definition, it is evaluated in the function call of the `fnt2` function. We use placeholders so that variables inside `ftn2` is clearly separated from the internal variables in `ftn1`:

```
ftn2[s1_, t1_, u1_] := ftn1 /. {s -> s1, t -> t1, u -> u1}
ftn2[2, 1, 2]
```

> 35 + Sin[2]^2

Suppose now, this is not enough and you need the numerical value, you can use `N[]` in the definition of the function,

```
ftn3[s1_, t1_, u1_] := N[ftn1 /. {s -> s1, t -> t1, u -> u1}]
ftn3[2, 1, 2]
```

> 35.8268

This should solve your problem!